# Fedora Error:error checking storage config

Tags: fedora, partition, system-installation, distributions

I have a PC with Windows 7 (ultimate) pre-installed on local disc C and have total of 1tb (approximately) on my HDD. I also have made an empty partition of 100Gb(97.66Gb) for installing Fedora 25 from a live usb (which is working properly). Now the problem comes when it asks the system partition, I select my hdd(name: ATA ST1000DM003...), which even shows the free space as stated before, but when I click on done, it shows error checking storage configuration, and the installer is stuck there. How do I proceed?

Comment: So you only want to create one 100 GB partition for Fedora? I'd suggest you save some of that space for swap as well at least. Please refer to this link from howtogeek.com : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35676/how-to-choose-a-partition-scheme-for-your-linux-pc/ to get an idea.

Comment: that is  not the point the 100 Gb partition is for testing,the fedora disk setup said that needs 4-5 Gb minimum. so i just made that partition, the problem is that fedora is still giving me error.if needed i will increase the empty partition.